# How to use cms systems like drupal and so on for crawl only?

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system, customization

I want to display the data by my own,

use cms to crawl the data only.

Anyone can share the experience and give me some clue where the entry point is?

Comment: Can you expand your question - I can't really tell what you're after. A CMS is just a content management system, it lets you edit your web pages and perform related tasks, it doesn't crawl the internet like a spider.

Comment: But most of cms users don't have a crawler themselves,how do they retrieve the data ?

Comment: CMS does not crawl. CMS = Content Management System, not Crawler Management System.

Comment: What data are they retrieving?

Comment: Maybe I should ask this way:how are most cms users retrieving their data?

Comment: What do you mean CMS users? Do you mean people who manage the content using the CMS? What data are they retrieving? The Content? Well the content is in stored by the CMS and it knows how to retrieve it.

Comment: Shore, fresh off your suspension and you ask another insanely vague, abstract question followed up with a (rare) comment that only raises more questions.

Answer (score 3):

I will re-interpret the question: *"How do I use Drupal to create and aggregate content, but display it through a means other than HTML web pages?"*

The answer is to focus on generating XML feeds. In Drupal Core, the default rss feed is at `/rss.xml`. Every taxonomy listing page also has an RSS feed associated with it. To expand further on those options, make use of the RSS feed display in Views, the [Views Datasource](http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource) module to add even greater varieties of data (JSON output, for example), and even the [RDF](http://drupal.org/project/rdf) projects if you want to be on the cutting edge.

If you do not want to display any of this content as HTML use `hook_menu_alter()` on almost every page generated in Drupal- run down every node and block it. At that point, this question becomes kind of academic, because if you are not interested in having a theme Layer, any CMS is the wrong tool for the job.